# Python3 and Qt Designer - Display an image in main window

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I'm still new with python and Qt designer. I would like to develop an application where user need to press the 'pushbutton' in order to view the image(from local directory path) on GUI mainwindow.This will keep repeating until complete number of cycle.

Did tried using QLabel and QGraphiscView widget but doesn't work.(probably due to lack of knowledge). Could anyone help me to solve it?

Below is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import division
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

gui_file = 'image.ui'

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(gui_file)

class showImage(QtGui.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
         QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
         Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
         self.setupUi(self)
         self.get_image_button.clicked.connect(self.getImage)

     def getImage(self):
         image_path='c:/Users/mohd_faizal4/Desktop/Python/Image/image1.jpg' #path to image file
         self.label_image.QPixmap(image_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = showImage()
    myWindow.show()
    sys.exit()
    app.exec_()
```

Really appreciate!

Comment: `self.label_image.setPixmap(QPixmap(image_path))`.

Comment: it's worked!. thanks for your valuable comment.